# Perl script is not fully executing when called from Java Program

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to execute my Perl script from Java program. I have already installed Perl in my computer. Below is my sample Perl file (`test.pl`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;
use autodie;

my $dir = path("E:/perl/scripts"); 
my $file = $dir->child("file.txt"); 
my $file_handle = $file->openw_utf8();

my @list=('a', 'list', 'of', 'lines');
push @list,<*.doc>;
push @list,<*.pdf>;
push @list,<*.jpg>;
push @list,<*.pl>;
print "Value of list = @list \n";
```

And this is my Java code to execute Perl script.

```
Process process;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c perl E:\\perl\\PerlCallbyServlet\\test.pl");
        //process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl E:\\perl\\PerlCallbyServlet\\test.pl");
        process.waitFor();
        if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Command Successful");
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command Failure");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Now first when I am trying to run this Java class I am getting below output.

```
Command Successful
Value of list = a list of lines
```

But when I am running this script from command prompt using command

```
perl test.pl
```

My output is as below:

```
Value of list = a list of lines one.doc test.pl photo.jpg
```

So I am not getting same output of a Perl script executing from Java program as from command prompt.

Comment: What’s the working directory in each case?

Comment: This is my working Directory for both case "E:\\perl\\PerlCallbyServlet" @Biffen

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that? Try letting the Perl script print its working directory. And are there `*.doc` etc files in *that* directory?

Comment: Yes, There are one .doc, one .jpg and one .pl file in this working Directory. @Biffen

Comment: Just to not leave any stone unturned: Do you know what *working* directory means? I.e. *not* the location of a script or binary.

Comment: Yes, working directory means from where I am executing my script

Comment: use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd; this is command to get working directory

Comment: And if you print `$dir`? Does it print what you expect when run from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Perl script does not set the working directory. I make the assumption that you want to add the contents of the directory `E:/perl/scripts` to `@list`. Try to add to the Perl script:

```
chdir('E:/perl/scripts');
```

Sorry, I do not use Windows, so I can't test if that is the correct path under Windows.